# PostgreSQL dual equivalent for query

Tags: sql, oracle, postgresql, oracle11g

I have Oracle Query as part of complex SQL script

```
"select sysdate into run_date from dual;"
```

The run_date is used elsewhere in the script.

I've converted this into PostgreSQL as

```
"select current_timestamp into lv_run_date"
```

since there is no dual equivalent in PostgreSQL. This works fine for first time and time stamp is stored.

However if run the query next time it throws error **relation "run_date" already exists**. I want current timestamp to be stored when it is run nexts time instead it throws error. How to fix it.

Comment: It looks like you've converted an Oracle PL/SQL script into a Postgre SQL query rather than into a Postgre PL/pgSQL script. `INTO` means "into a variable" in PL/pgSQL (just as in PL/SQL) , but means "into a table" (i.e. create table) in Postgre's SQL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The select wasn't necessary in PL/SQL to begin with, and it's not necessary in PL/pgSQL either. Just assign the value:

```
lv_run_date := current_timestamp;
```